# GridDB node.js client database connection error

Tags: node.js, griddb

I am following [ThisDocument](https://griddb.net/en/blog/getting-started-with-the-griddb-nodejs-client/) to install GridDB node.js client. But, stuck at last. The installation worked fine but during, Database connection process I got **reference error**.
What reference does it require?
What are the steps to connect grid DB instance with js?
I used this code inside js file named n.js

```
var fs     = require('fs');
var factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
var store = factory.getStore({
                        "host": process.argv[2],
                        "port": process.argv[3],
                        "cluster_name": process.argv[4],
                        "username": process.argv[5],
                        "password": process.argv[6]});
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6L7o.png)

I am following `[ThisDocument ](https://griddb.net/en/blog/getting-started-with-the-griddb-nodejs-client/)`to install GridDB node.js client. But, stuck at last. The installation worked fine but during, Database connection process I got reference error. What reference does it require? What are the steps to connect grid DB instance with js? I used this code inside js file named n.js